# Which gremlinquery I have to execute to get different clients with the same filehash from a specifig database?

Tags: c#, gremlin

I have this Database:

```
Clients => Incident => File => Filename
```

- Clients have an ID
- Incidents have an ID and a reportedOn property
- Files have an ID and a fileSize, mimeType, malware property
- Filenames have an ID
- Client have an outgoing Edge to Incidents (reported), incident have an outgoing Edge to file (containsFile), file have an outgoing Edge to filename (hasName).

Here is some sample Data:

```
g.addV('client').property('id','1').as('1').
  addV('incident').property('id','11').property('reportedON', '2/15/2019 8:01:19 AM').as('11').
  addV('file').property('id','100').property('fileSize', '432534').as('100').
  addV('fileName').property('id','file.pdf').as('file.pdf').
  addE('reported').from('1').to('11').
  addE('containsFile').from('11').to('100').
  addE('hasName').from('100').to('file.pdf').iterate()
```

I want to know which clients have got the same file-id over their incidens. For example clientOne reported an incident which containsFile with the file-id 100 and clientTwo reported an incident which also cointainsFile with the file-id 100.

What is the best query to get this result. The result can be manipulated witch C# Code if it is not possible to get the result direct from the gremlinquery.

Comment: I want to get the clients which have the same file-id over their incidents and the file-id which was send to these clients.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Did you try something on your own?

Comment: Yes, I tried to get the right resultset but it did not work. What ist wrong aboud my question?

Comment: Your sample data contains only one client. Please provide more data and the expected result.